# Persisting dates and times in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, date

Apparently neither `java.util.Date` nor `java.util.Calendar` implement `Persistable`, so cannot be used in `Persistable` classes.  What is the best alternative for persisting dates and times?

Answer (score 2):

You could write your code to expect that dates and times are kept in the Unix epoch format (number of seconds since 1/1/1970). Then your problem is simply a matter of storing a long number.

Comment: Does this account for time zones?

Comment: No but neither does java.util.Date. Java's date/time handling is pretty basic.

Comment: @Amanda S: It depends on what you mean by "account for".  Date.setTime(long) assumes GMT, and Date.getTime() uses GMT to do the conversion.  So these are consistent with each other, regardless of the device timezone settings.  This means the long value is suitable for storage in a database, or elsewhere.  If the device timezone is changed, then the Calendar formatting class will change the time appropriately, but the epoch time doesn't change.   So I would say "yes" to the question of whether this handles time zones.

Answer (score 1):

storing as a long as Dan mentions is the way to go.  `System.currentTimeMillis()` will return milliseconds since Unix Epoch, which is 1/1/1970 GMT.  It's obviously fairly trivial to convert between seconds and milliseconds.  For timezone corrections, the [Calendar](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/Calendar.html) class can help you handle this.

Note:

```
getInstance(Timezone zone)
getTimeInMillis()
setTimeInMillis(long millis)
setTimeZone(Timezone value)
```